# How to set up local repository for PPM?

Tags: perl

I am using Active Perl and am looking for ways to set up a local repository to install various modules. Main reason behind is the production server has no internet access.

Can anyone point me any quick start or step-by-step tutorials on this?

Answer (score 1):

- There is a tutorial on how to install from a local repository (manually) [here](http://www.anaesthetist.com/mnm/perl/ppmlocal.htm)
- There are descriptions how someone did it [here (perlmonks)](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=559293) and [here (perl.com)](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2007/01/11/painless-ppm.html?page=2)

To use the GUI ppm manager most likely requires a httpd (a.k. web server) that gives PPM access to the *.ppd and *.tgz files over http. I'm not sure I'd choose that over doing it from the command line.